# How to make Column type series Secondary yAxis values dynamic and not always start with 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Refer this jsfiddle link first:

https://jsfiddle.net/sq7n69dh/17/

Here, In this above example the **spline** type series (Series 2) **primary yAxis (left side)** doesn't start with 0% it takes the dynamic value based on the series data range.

The same thing I want in the **column**  type series (Series 2) **Secondary yAxis (right side)** i.e. instead of staring with $0, it should start with some dynamic value based on the series data range.

** The main reason is to make the minute change in the values for Series 2 to be differentiated properly in the chart view. I mean for minute changes in value of Series 2, the column height looks kind of equal on chart view.

When I change the type for Series 2 from column to spline, it works.
So does it means we can't have yAxis dynamic plotting for column series and it
will always start with 0 value ??

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

    <div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
            height: 298,
      marginTop: 33
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
                    "Current",
                    "30 Days",
                    "60 Days",
                    "90 Days"
                        ],
    },
    yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:,.1f}%'
                }
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                labels: {
                    format: '$' + '{value:,.0f}'
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
    series: [{"name":"Series 1",
              "data":[95.19,95.93,95.93,95.93],
              "type":"spline",
              "color":"#88CB11",
              "yAxis":0},
              {"name":"Series 2",
              "data":[601.02,603.81,600.31,599.9],
              "type":"column",
              "color":"#4472C4",
              "yAxis":1}]
});
```

[HighChart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKZXm.png)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your requirement, but you can change this value by setting `yAxis.min`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min

Comment: @Sebastian - Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/sq7n69dh/17/  - Here for Series 2 of type column, I don't want the secondary yAxis  to start with $0, instead I want the plotting to be dynamic, the same way its happening with Series 1 yAxis (starting with 95.1%, not with 0%) for the given series "data":[95.19,95.93,95.93,95.93].
Hence, I want  the yAxis for Series 2 of type column to start with 598 or something for series "data":[601.02,603.81,600.31,599.9]. Also based on different data range the plotting on yAxis should change and not start with 0 value always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments (thanks for the clarification) - I think that the best solution for this case will be finding the smallest value in the series and set it as a `yAxis.min` in the `load` callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2yq4bcn/

```
events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this,
      lowestValue;

    lowestValue = chart.series[1].points.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y)

    chart.yAxis[1].update({
      min: lowestValue[0].y
    })
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: Thanks Bro, but what happens in the above solution is I'm not getting any column for the smallest values in the series. I mean can we assign yAxis.min as something less than that of the smallest values, So as to get the column for the smallest values.

Need to have solution for the below data set, and have column for all the values.

Data 1 - https://jsfiddle.net/gq5rxzj9/3/
Data 2 - https://jsfiddle.net/rtjo9w0x/23/

Comment: @J.Bhardwaj you can define the `yAxis.min` as the 90 % or 99% of the lowest value, depends on your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lkgpr6wf/

Comment: Also, I'm new to these HighCharts, I like to know is there any efficient way to lean the rules of HighCharts or What all basic things/topics should I know to get a good hold on HighChats fundamentals ?

Comment: @J.Bhardwaj I think that all basic stuff you can find in the API documentation: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highcharts

Comment: The above code snippet is not working in IE 11 (in chrome its working ), could you please refactor the same. I'm also trying from my side.

Comment: @J.Bhardwaj It doesn't work in the IE 11 because IE doesn't support the ES6 solutions like arrow function which is used in this demo. Try to change the arrow function to the regular one and test it again.

Comment: Wedzel Yes, I have changed the arrow function to the regular functions and its working in IE 11 as well. Thanks a lot for all your help.